# How to enumerate 2 touch points objective C

Tags: ios, uitouch

To find co ordinates of 2 touch points, then find distance between 2 points and hence to generate center to rotate around, I'm using following piece of code. I'm not sure if this is best way to do it.

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent: (UIEvent *)event

<SOME CODE>


if([touches count] == 2){
    for(touch in touches){
        if(self.pt1Flag){
            self.pt2=[touch locationInView:self.superview];
            self.pt2Flag = YES;
            self.pt1Flag = NO;
        }
        else{
            self.pt1 = [touch locationInView:self.superview];
            self.pt1Flag = YES;
            self.pt2Flag = NO;
        }

    }
}

self.delta = [self lengthDifferencePoint:self.pt1 andPoint:self.pt2 equiDistantFromPoint:self.center];

<SOME CODE>

}
```

There  is mostly for single finger touch. Is there a proper way to do it? 
Also I understand there is

```
 [touches enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, BOOL *stop){
}];
```

can somebody please explain usage of this block to find coordinates of touch point or any better/cleaner solution than mine.

Comment: Is there a good reason for not using a UIRotateGestureRecognizer? It really makes things easier and aligns better with the expected platform behaviour http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIRotateGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Initial requirement was to implement touch using 1 finger only using a handler on right corner. requirement changed later to extend that functionality to 2 fingers too, so instead of re-doing everything with rotation gesture-recognizer, I was trying to achieve that using existing code

Comment: `<SOME CODE>` is basically rest of code for one finger-touch in handler and main view. It's supposed to work exactly as you can see in aviary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

enumerateObjectsUsingBlock will not help you in this case, you are not filtering or doing any sort of process in the objects. In fact the for-in loop itself also enumerates the objects.

But if you know there are only 2 objects you don't need to traverse them, you can simply:

```
    NSArray *touchesArray = [touches allObjects];
    self.pt1 = [touchesArray[0] locationInView:self.superview];
    self.pt2 = [touchesArray[1] locationInView:self.superview];
```

Comment: Thanks. exactly what I needed. Loop was kinda making me uncomfortable :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *touchesArray = [touches allObjects];
for (int i=0; i< [touchesArray count]; i++) {
    NSString *variable = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pt%d",i];
    [self setValue:[touchesArray objectAtIndex:i] forKey:variable];
}
```